how to add ./bin/op-batcher to op-batcher folder in optimism L2 solution
I'm trying to run
./bin/op-batcher --l2-eth-rpc=http://localhost:8545 --rollup-rpc=http://localhost:9545 --poll-interval=1s --sub-safety-margin=6 --num-confirmations=1 --safe-abort-nonce-too-low-count=3 --resubmission-timeout=30s --rpc.addr=0.0.0.0 --rpc.port=8548 --rpc.enable-admin --max-channel-duration=25 --l1-eth-rpc=$L1_RPC_URL --private-key=$GS_BATCHER_PRIVATE_KEY
but getting this error
bash: ./bin/op-batcher: No such file or directory
My question is, how do i add the bin folder and the op-batcher file?

Can you share the steps you've taken to install the local node? So I can check if you've missed something
